# How to have an image in the footer of the last page of a MS Word document?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2007, headers, footers

I need to create a document, which I will use as a template for many other documents, that contains a header that appears on the first page only, and a footer on the last page only. The length of the document will vary.

I've seen a number of different ways doing this using fields and conditions, and this works great for headers & footers that are **text** based.

However, this document requires that both the header & footer are **images**, and no text at all.

Is there any way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by including in the footer a field that contains :

```
{ IF { PAGE } = { NUMPAGES } { INCLUDEPICTURE "FileName" [Switches] } }
```

For more information see :

[Using Last-page Headers and Footers](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008712_Using_Last-page_Headers_and_Footers.html)
[Field codes: IncludePicture field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/field-codes-includepicture-field-HA102017478.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put a "Section Break (Continuous)" into the template. 
Put the image into the footer of Section 2. 
Tell your users to insert all their text above the section break (and don't delete it).

Comment: A Continuous section break (unlike the other section breaks) doesn't create a new Header/Footer section that can be edited independently so this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, at the risk of splitting hairs: yes it does, but the new header and footer don’t start appearing until the first *full page* of the new section; i.e., after a page break. So, you’re right; this answer won’t work for you. Sorry for posting it without testing it first.